# Keyboard opens, the view gets readjusted based on the space left

Tags: android, react-native, flexbox

I have a two views with `flex:0.8` and `flex:0.2` as follow:

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
   <View style={{flex:0.8}}>
      <TextInput
         keyboardType="numeric"
       />
   </View>
   <View style={{flex:0.2}}>
   </View>
</View>
```

When I focus on textinput, the keyboard opens and my two views automatically adjust themselves with the space left on top of the keyboard. 
How can I prevent this automatic readjustment?

Answer (score 0):

You can check about keyboard input mode on https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-keyboard-adjust
The behavior that you got here is because you didn't specify the adjust, so "adjustUnspecified" will be used as default. It will make android decide by itself what kind of adjust it will use depends on the current layout.
You can use "adjustNothing" or "adjustPan" to make sure that android will not resize your views